# Freeze when starting Windriver os

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arch-linux

When I start Windriver OS, it always freeze. And it shows this text in console window:

```
acpid: 0 rules loaded <br>
acpid: waiting for events <br>
Starting advanced configuration and power interface daemon: acpid
```

I read some documents and I think I should disaple acpi service. And when the grub show:"Wind river intelligent device platform", I press "e" to edit. New windows was showed with two line:

```
root(hd0,1)
kernel /boot/bzImage root=UUID=... nwnoatime=rootwait reboot=bios
```

I have added "acpi=off" in the end of second line, but when i start os with new command, it show: "halting the system due to suspicious kernel"

Please help me. Thanks you. And sorry if my english is not good

Comment: What do you mean by "Windriver OS" ? VxWorks ? Windriver Linux ?

Comment: google doesnt find anything for "Windriver", there is WIND RIVER, though .... is it THAT hard to push the space bar?

Comment: yes, i mean "Windriver linux"